# Yandex Suggests (интервалы между запросами(debounce))

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const addressesInfo = ref('')
const YandexSuggest = ref<any>(null)

const initialYandexSearch = () => {
  YandexSuggest.value = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest')
  console.log(YandexSuggest.value)
}

onMounted(() => {
  initialYandexSearch()
})
</script>

<template>
  <v-text-field label="Поиск" type="text" append-inner-icon="mdi-magnify" id="suggest" />
</template>
```

Как можно сделать debounce на input? В данный момент api запрос отправляется на каждый добавленный символ